# Route [admin.funcionarios] not defined

Tags: php, laravel

I have this:

```
Route::get('/admin/funcionarios', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'funcionarios'])->name('funcionarios');
```

and this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Funcionarios;

class FuncionarioController extends Controller {

    public function destroy($id) {
        $funcionario = Funcionarios::find($id);
        $funcionario->delete();
        return redirect()->route('admin.funcionarios');
    }
}
```

The problem is I get this error: Route [admin.funcionarios] not defined. (Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException)
Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: is this route in a group that is adding the `admin.` name? otherwise it would just be `funcionarios` as you defined

Comment: It is a page inside admin. admin/funcionarios.

Comment: can you show your route group that is adding this 'admin.' route name prefix ?

Comment: `Route::get('/admin', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('admin');`

Comment: that isn't a route group that is just a route named `admin` .. that has no effect on any other routes

Comment: So I don't know how to do it ;/

Comment: just name your route `admin.funcionarios` instead of `funcionarios` if you want it to have that name; unless you have a bunch of routes you want to prefix the 'admin.' route name to

Comment: oh, it works, thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing `$funcionario = Funcionarios::find($id);`? I gave you an answer 3 hours ago that saves you having to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can name your route what you would like, so instead of `funcionarios` you could name it `admin.funcionarios` if you prefer:

```
Route::get(...)->name('admin.funcionarios');
```

You can also use a Route Group to cascade this `admin.` name to the routes inside of it if you want:

```
Route::name('admin.')->group(function () {
    Route::get(...)->name('funcionarios');
});
```

Now that route name for that route would be `admin.funcionarios` as route groups "cascade" configuration.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Routing - Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Routing - Route Groups - Route Name Prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-name-prefixes)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`Route::get('/admin/funcionarios',['as' => 'admin.funcionarios', App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'funcionarios']);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return redirect()->route('admin.funcionarios');

Try to change :

```
Route::get('/admin/funcionarios', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'funcionarios'])->name('funcionarios');
```

To

```
Route::get('/admin/funcionarios', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'funcionarios'])->name('admin.funcionarios');
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can do it like this:

```
public function destroy($id) {
    $funcionario = Funcionarios::find($id);
    $funcionario->delete();
    return redirect()->route('funcionarios');
}
```

if what the name part of the route is, you must write it in parentheses.